# Comparison of statistical experiments - A generalization of Blackwell's theorem for the binary case

Tags: statistics

The notion of *being more informative* (usually denoted $\succeq$) as a way comparing statistical experiments is well known and it is characterized by the Blackwell-Sherman-Stein theorem.

Blackwell introduced the notion *being more informative for $k$-decision problems* (usually denoted $\succeq_k$), and he showed that for two experiments $E$ and $F$, it is the case that $E\succeq F$ if and only if $E\succeq_k F$ for all $k\geq 1$.

He further showed that if the parameter space $\Theta$ has size 2 (i.e., $|\Theta|=2$), then it is sufficient to look at $k=2$. More precisely, he showed that for any two statistical experiments $E$ and $F$ with a parameter space $\Theta$ of size 2, we have $E\succeq F$ if and only $E\succeq_2 F$.

I am wondering if there is a generalization of this result to the non-binary case. More precisely, assume that the size of the parameter space is $|\Theta|=m>2$, do we known whether there exists $k=k(m)$ such that for any two experiments $E$ and $F$ with parameter space $\Theta$ of size m, we have $E\succeq F$ if and only $E\succeq_k F$?